# Icon for Telecommunications Services

Tags: website-design, icon, symbolism

I'm working on a service quality monitoring dashboard for my employer. The site diplays QoS parameters for hundreds of different telecommunications services provided by the company: messaging, voice calls, internet connection, television, websites, mobile applications etc.

For the site I need an **icon**, which denotes **a telecommunications service of any type**, that is, which can be used for any of the above listed services. I currently use a **cogwheel icon** ([mdi-cog-outline](https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/5.1.45/)), but I'd like to use something **more telecom-related**. Any ideas?

Comment: Questions asking to gather ideas are not really a great fit here, it's just too broad.

Comment: Have a look on the nounproject.  It's usually the first place I head when I'm stuck for an idea. If there isnt' one that's a perfect fit for your requirments you could potentially modify one that's close. I'm not affiliated with that website in any way.

Comment: @Luciano there are many "what icon represents X" questions here. --- kol, I would ask what do you want such an icon to convey?? "telecom-related' could mean **anything** - a phone, a tower, a handset, a CB, a radio, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Different ways to approach this, some inspiration via the Noun Project:

- https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=communication
- https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=network

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that cogwheel does not directly relate to telecom.  As it is used by Apple, it means "settings", or more broadly, behind the scenes processes.

Look at the essence of your list of services - at the most basic level it is data transmission, and at some stage it is all transmitted wirelessly via radio waves. I would recommend full or partial radio tower icon, with waives emanating from it, this has been standard representation of radio and television for decades.  Or you can combine cogwheel and radio, to represent "behind the scenes processes of data transmission".